# How can I hide input blue caret in the ios webview?

Tags: javascript, css, ios, iphone, webview

There is a custom react component for some sms code.
This component made of one simple input which overlayed on a styled view block (divs with borders and numbers)

input styles

```
width: 252px;
height: 52px;
line-height: 28px;
box-sizing: initial;
border: 0;
font-family: 'MTS';
background: transparent;
position: absolute;
color: transparent;
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
z-index: 2;
font-size: 50px;
letter-spacing: 18px;
caret-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
outline: none;
```

In the code styles above, native blue caret of input is hidden, however on ios webview 6,7,8 and xr iphones, blue caret still exist
(on Android and all browsers everything is okay including safari)

[image]

How could I hide it at all?